# Как унаследоваться от родительского класса?

Tags: python, python-2.x

Есть ли способ классу `Mail` унаследовать класс `Program`, кроме способа передачи в `Mail` экземпляра `Program`? Что-то иные варианты у меня не работают.

```
from kivy.app import App


class Mail(object):
    def __init__(self, program):
        self.pr = program

    def get_var(self):
        print self.pr.var


class Program(App):
    def __init__(self, **kvargs):
        super(Program, self).__init__(**kvargs)
        self.var = True

        b= Mail(self)
        b.get_var()


program = Program()
```

Comment: А `class Mail(Program):` не получится?

Comment: Mail ничего не знает о Program. Я не могу так указать родителя, так это вызовет ошибку.

Comment: Что мешает поменять местами объявления `Mail` и `Program`?

Comment: Тогда Program ничего не будет знать о Mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from kivy.app import App

class Mail(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x()

    def get_var(self):
        print self.var


class Program(Mail, App):
    def __init__(self, **kvargs):
        super(Program, self).__init__()
        self.var = True
        self.get_var()

    def x(self):
        print('I function x class Program')


   program = Program()
```

Answer (score 1):

За счёт того, что Python является динамическим языком программирования, ничего страшного не произойдёт, если вы будете использовать класс `Mail` внутри класса `Program` и при этом класс `Mail` ещё не будет создан.

Поэтому можно действительно просто поменять местами объявления одного и другого классов:

```
from kivy.app import App


class Program(App):
    def __init__(self, **kvargs):
        super(Program, self).__init__(**kvargs)
        self.var = True

        b = Mail(self)
        b.get_var()


class Mail(Program):
    def __init__(self, program):
        self.pr = program

    def get_var(self):
        print self.pr.var


program = Program()
```

В момент объявления класса `Program` будет требоваться наличие класса `App`, который используется в объявлении родителей.

В момент объявления класса `Mail` будет требоваться наличие класса `Program`, который уже будет к этому моменту доступен в области видимости.